# Awk/Sed: Replacing a specific character in a line by index (after getting the value from grep)

Tags: awk, sed

Below i have found the value to change in the file.

```
value_to_change=$(grep "$mbean" "$instr_file_path" | awk -F= '{print $2}' | awk -v awk_index="$index" '{print $awk_index}')
```

I want to do a sed on that line to replace the specific value at the specific place. Note that this may be a 0, 1 whatever so ill need to know where it is in the line to do the find and replace in that area only.

How do i go about this?

Comment: Please add sample of Input and sample of output in your post too now in CODE TAGS.

Comment: Whatever it is you're trying to do you do **not** need grep plus awk plus awk plus sed to do it!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -v term="$mbean" -v index="$index" \
         '$0~term{split($0,r,"="); 
                  split(r[2],fields); 
                  print fields[index]}' file
```

obviously not tested...

However, I guess this wasn't really your question.  Do you want to replace the value at that index? With what other value?

Comment: Hi, yes to replace it with a variable $value